# Problem with variable in Typescript/Express

Tags: typescript, express, rest

I'm trying a rest api with TS and Express. For the login section I have to get pre-generated `salt` to encrypt a password and move on.
Take a look at this code:

```js
    const { user, pwd } = req.body;
    
    let salt : String = ""; //Declared empty
    let hash : String = ""; //Declared empty

    (await DB).query("select salt from sf_guard_user where username = ?", [user])
    .then(function(data) {
      salt = data[0].salt;
      hash = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(salt + pwd).digest('hex');
    });
    console.log(salt, hash); //Still empty

    //...
```

How can I access these values outside my `query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is asynchronous by nature. Judging by your program, the `console.log` will be run before the `await`ed function is complete. So, the way so fix this is as follows:

Using Promises (like you do in the example):

```js
(await DB).query("select salt from sf_guard_user where username = ?", [user])
.then(function(data) {
  salt = data[0].salt;
  hash = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(salt + pwd).digest('hex');

  console.log(salt, hash);
  // do rest of function here...
});
```

This will ensure that the `console.log` will be run after the asynchronous function has been finished. All `Promise`s / asynchronous functions are like that.

Further reading: [Promise in MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Note: In my opinion, it's better to use the new `async/await` rather than Promises, but some cases are better handled using Promises.

Comment: Thank you, my session method was already async so I just added the await to my query and problem resolved..

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. Thanks .